# PHP Facebook session management

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a facebook app using PHP.
I am able to login using the below code

```
 <?php

$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/sandysfirst/";
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" .urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope="."publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access";
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
       echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {

}?>

<?php
  include_once "src/facebook.php";
  $app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  $application_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => $app_id,
 'fileUpload' =>true,
 'secret' => $application_secret,
 'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
       if ($facebook->getSession()) {
       $user = $facebook->getUser();
       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
              $fbme  =   $facebook->api('/me');
              echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/> Welcome ".$fbme['name'];
         }
       echo "<html>
```

and the HTML follows below that with a form action.
I want to know how I can get the same user id or session on the second page once the form is submitted.
I am not using facebook.php of sdk 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the facebook api, but from some basic php there's a few methods you could use:

1 - Add the uid as a hidden field in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="$uid">
```

2 - Add it to the action url

```
<form action="submit.php?uid=$uid">
```

However the better way is to use the facebook api, pretty much the same way you've got it listed there already (from the `include_once "src/facebook.php";`), to retrieve the uid each time, otherwise you leave it open to security hacks (easy to pass a fake uid in a form).

Comment: Thank you for help. My form action calls a javascript function where in based on calculation different pages are called. I can put in href="1.php?uid=$uid" as you mentioned above. But how I can use the uid on the next page to tag a photo of the tag a photo and upload it on the user profile. Do I need to create array of facebook again as in the above code? or the uid itself will be sufficient. Please help.

Comment: If you plan on tagging photos / uploading photos / adding wall comments / etc, then you have to use the facebook code again each time.  The uid will not be sufficient.

Instead of copy/pasting the facebook code each time you could instead put it in a seperate file and use a `include('fb.php')` to call it each time.  Use it as is to get the uid on each page and from there run the facebook photo commands (you'll need to look up how to do photo tagging and uploading on the api documentation or tutorials).

Comment: Ok I can go on next page and get the user name as per your suggestion(using facebook code each time).Can you help me with photo tagging and publishing on user wall please?. I don't have any access token saved anywhere as you can see in my code. Is it possible this way?